# iOS Simulator crashes on macOS Monterey

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

After I updated macOS on macbook with M1, my project crashes when running on any iOS simulator (runs correctly on physical devices). I am using firebase, GoogleSignIn and FacebookLogin as my pod packages. I noticed that other projects without pods run correctly on simulators. I've tried both latest public version of xcode 12.5 and first beta of xcode 13. Neither of them works.
Crash report looks as follows:

```
CrashReporter Key:   6A42AE7B-E923-027C-2A0C-C8BB6FEC5FCA
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             ToSports [10111]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9F8401F5-AAAE-4F54-A093-5E26F429FC8C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/321B292E-186C-445A-882D-D604A59C7183/ToSports.app/ToSports
Identifier:          com.ToSports
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      Exited process [10134]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.9F8401F5-AAAE-4F54-A093-5E26F429FC8C [5668]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1056]

Date/Time:           2021-06-10 14:00:11.9151 +0300
Launch Time:         2021-06-10 14:00:05.8233 +0300
OS Version:          macOS 12.0 (21A5248p)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4367589376
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      mapped file                 104542000-10489e000    [ 3440K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=b8410d3f
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [10111]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:



Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7fff98bd8 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x104f1ee3c ???
2   dyld                                   0x20527b88f dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 890
3   dyld                                   0x20527a6b5 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 244
4   dyld                                   0x20527a4b4 start + 388
5   dyld                                   0x205275000 ???

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7fff85320 ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7fff9e1a0 ???

Thread 2:: com.apple.rosetta.debugserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7fff85320 ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7fff9e1a0 ???


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010cf75af8  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x000000010d636000
   r8: 0x7273e846fc4100e3   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000000010d636000  r11: 0x000000010d43f010
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x000000010d43f060  r14: 0x00000002052e9080  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: <unavailable>       rfl: 0x0000000000000283
 tmp0: 0x0000000104f0cc64 tmp1: 0x0000000104f0bf8c tmp2: 0x0000000205293ca3


Binary Images:
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x205275000 -        0x2052dcfff dyld (*) <4e207376-cc5d-3986-a0bd-4d09f4217e68> /usr/lib/dyld

EOF

Model: MacBookAir10,1, BootROM 7429.0.72.0.3, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_AppleM1Item, Apple M1, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi, wl0: May  4 2021 18:24:35 version 18.20.281.2.7.8.107 FWID 01-7c11bd60
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
```

Has anyone faced such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues and tried all kinds of work-a-rounds. In the end, upgrade to Monterey Beta 3 and the issue will go away.